# 2.8 How do I add texture and transparency to look identical via FBX?

Tags: texturing, .fbx

Usually in 2.79, In this example, the UV mapping is already done, I create a new material, click on the texture tab, click on new, select an image or open a new image, and the texture appears on the material icon, the model, and the texture appears in the preview.

But in 2.8 that is not happening and I don't know why. Also, there use to be a transparency box to tick and select an opacity amount but that is gone as well.

This method allowed me to export textures and opacities that FBX was able to understand.

So how can I have a WYSIWYG in the viewport to have the same results when opened with FBX?

Comment: thats what I wanted to know too!

Comment: This would be a much needed addon for anyone who exports models for game engines. On FBX export simulate a blender internal equivalent (closest possible) then export and keep the Blender file and nodes intact.